# How to create Swiper instance (Swiper.js) on mobile view and destory instance on desktop view in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I want to initialize swiper on mobile screen and destroy on desktop screen everytime. I know I can use "display: block" and "display:none" property in CSS but I want better approach to show and hide swiper.
I am trying to solve this issue but whenever I try to destroy the instance with "swiper.destroy()" it works but when I try to reinitialize the swiper again on mobile screen it does not work because the refrence is already destroyed with swiper. I want to show swiper on the mobile screen and list of products (rather than swiper) on desktop screen.

I tried the following code...

```
<div>
<swiper
          slides-per-view="auto"
          :speed= 600
          @swiper="onSwiper"
          :centered-slides= "true"
          :centered-slides-bounds= "true"
        >
          <swiper-slide
            v-for="(item, index) in Products" :key="index"
          >
            <customComponent :product="item" />
          </swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
</div>
```

Inside script tag:

```
data() {
      return {
        swiperRef: null,
      };
}, 

methods: {
     destroySwiper() {
        if(window.innerWidth > 768){
          this.swiperRef.destroy()
        } else {
          this.swiperRef.init()
        }
      },

      onSwiper(swiper) {
        this.swiperRef = swiper;
      }
},

mounted () {

      this.destroySwiper()
      window.addEventListener('resize',this.destroySwiper);
},
```